# GradientAnimation ONLY Works in AnimatableModifier, Other Simultaneous Animations Working Regardless (SwiftUI)

Tags: swift, animation, swiftui, gradient

I'm having a lot of trouble narrowing down the underlying implementation that might cause things to work this way. I've tried tons of combinations of using `@State` vs initializing, overlays, whatever.

**1.**
The only thing that works is when it is in an `AnimatableModifier`.

**2.**
Other animations on the same view, and based on same value work regardless.

**Visual Example**

You can see the scale animation working fine, but only the bottom rectangle is animating the gradient

[image: gradient-issue]

**Reproducible Code**

I got some of the original code [here](https://swiftui-lab.com/swiftui-animations-part3/). They mention weird issues with containers, but it's not clear what is expected behavior and otherwise

Works with Previews

**NOTE:** if you're using previews, make sure to play or animations won't run at all

```
import SwiftUI
import UIKit

public struct AnimatableGradient: View, Animatable {
    public let from: [Color]
    public let to: [Color]
    public var pct: CGFloat
    
    public var animatableData: CGFloat {
        get { pct }
        set { pct = newValue }
    }

    private var current: [Color] {
        zip(from, to).map { from, to in
            from.mix(with: to, percent: pct)
        }
    }

    public var body: some View {
        LinearGradient(
            gradient: Gradient(colors: current),
            startPoint: UnitPoint(x: 0, y: 0),
            endPoint: UnitPoint(x: 1, y: 1)
        )
        /// temporary to show that animating is working
        .scaleEffect(1 - (0.2 * pct))
    }
}

// MARK: AnimatableModifier

struct PassthroughModifier<Body: View>: AnimatableModifier {
    var animatableData: CGFloat
    let body: (CGFloat) -> Body
    
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        // also works to just pass body(animatableData)
        content.overlay(body(animatableData))
    }
}

// MARK: Content

fileprivate struct GradientExample: View, Animatable {
    @State var pct: CGFloat = 0
    
    private var base: some View {
        Rectangle()
            .fill(.black)
            .frame(width: 200, height: 100)
    }
    
    private func gradient(pct: CGFloat) -> some View {
        AnimatableGradient(from: [.orange, .red],
                           to: [.blue, .green],
                           pct: pct)
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            base.overlay(
                gradient(pct: pct)
            )

            base.modifier(
                PassthroughModifier(animatableData: pct){ pct in
                    gradient(pct: pct)
                }
            )
        }
        .onAppear{
            withAnimation(.linear(duration: 2.8).repeatForever(autoreverses: true)) {
                self.pct = pct == 0 ? 1 : 0
            }
        }
    }
}

// MARK: Preview

struct GradientPreview: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        GradientExample()
    }
}

// MARK: Helpers

extension Color {
    public var components: (r: Double, g: Double, b: Double, a: Double) {
        /// passing through UIColor because things like `Color.red`
        /// always return `nil` otherwise :/
        let comps = UIColor(self).cgColor.components ?? []
        return (
            comps[safe: 0] ?? 0,
            comps[safe: 1] ?? 0,
            comps[safe: 2] ?? 0,
            comps[safe: 3] ?? 0
        )
    }
}

extension Array {
    subscript(safe idx: Int) -> Element? {
        guard idx < count else { return nil }
        return self[idx]
    }
}

extension Color {
    public func mix(with other: Color, percent: Double) -> Color {
        let left = self.components
        let right = other.components
        let r = left.r + right.r - (left.r * percent)
        let g = left.g + right.g - (left.g * percent)
        let b = left.b + right.b - (left.b * percent)
        
        return Color(red: Double(r), green: Double(g), blue: Double(b))
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the issue in your question?

Comment: @swiftPunk how to animate the gradient via the view directly, or a good explanation as to why it will never work. (ideally addressing why other animations on the same object work and what is different about the two) :)

Comment: As I can see in your code, your project is kind of complex for such a question, if your issue is about Color or specially about Color+Animation I recommend make your code simple as possible, for example i am talking about mixing Color-Animation issue with gradient direction-Animation here.

Comment: I get it, it's kind of a nuanced issue, but hoping somebody spots it who has a bit of insight into the animation environment or what is going wrong here. I don't know a way to reduce it further. If it's still nagging at me, maybe I'll throw a bounty on or sth

Comment: works perfectly in my Simulator iPhone 12 iOS15.2, Xcode 13.2.1

Comment: I just double checked to see if maybe it was a canvas-previews issue, and I get the same result in simulator. I'm on m1 mac, if maybe relevant

Comment: also works in my preview!